# virtualbox(ubuntu 20.04) on host macOS stopped connecting to internet

Tags: server, virtualbox

The host is macOS 11.2.2. The guest is Ubuntu 20.04
This is my network setting on VirtualBox.

```
Bridged Adapter
en0: Wi-Fi(Airport)

Allow all
```

This is the `ip a` output from Ubuntu:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f4:32:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.110/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 7158sec preferred_lft 7158sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef4:329b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ea:81:8e:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It stopped connecting internet. Can any expert help me out? THANK YOU!

[image]

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Your output shows that interface `enp0s3` has an IP address: 192.168.2.110. Is that an appropriate IP address for your LAN? Does your router have that listed as a DHCP client?

Comment: I think that is valid. The guest can ping host can the host can ping guest. But the guest cannot connect to Internet.

Comment: Then it does not seem to be a network problem. Check your firewall settings on the host and guest.

Comment: And on guest, when I changed Bridged Adapter to NAT it can connect to internet...
But I need Bridged Adapter for the SSH. So I have to figure out why Bridged Adapter cannot connect to internet.

Comment: sorry but can you show me how to check firewall setting?

Comment: That's a completely separate question. Use the Search box at the top of the page to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

After macOS upgrade the issue has gone!